# Java RandomAccessFile , Only finds the first entry

Tags: java

When my program reads from the randomaccessfile it will only find the first file or the file with the lowest account number ( this is a banking program )
After that I get the IO exception with a read error

```
private RandomAccessFile input; // Random Aecess File input Stream

private Record data;

public static JFrame frame = new JFrame();


public CredRead() // Constructor CredRead created


{

    // open the file
    try {

        // declare the output stream object and associate it to file
        // file.dat
        input = new RandomAccessFile("UnionDB.dat", "rw");

    }

    catch (IOException e) {
        // if an error occurs display a message on the screen
        System.err.println("File not opened properly\n " + e.toString());

        // the program terminates due to error
        System.exit(1);
    }

    data = new Record();

    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(650, 400));
    frame.setSize(getPreferredSize()); // Frame Size
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(7, 2)); // Grid Layout set

    /* GUI Components */

    frame.add(new Label("Enter Account Number and click Enter"));
    account_num = new TextField();
    frame.add(account_num);
    account_num.addActionListener(this);

    frame.add(new Label("First Name"));
    first_name = new TextField(20);
    first_name.setEditable(false);
    frame.add(first_name);

    frame.add(new Label("Last Name"));
    last_name = new TextField(20);
    last_name.setEditable(false);
    frame.add(last_name);

    frame.add(new Label("Available Funds"));
    balance = new TextField(20);
    balance.setEditable(false);
    frame.add(balance);

    frame.add(new Label("Overdraft Limit"));
    overdraft = new TextField(20);
    overdraft.setEditable(false);
    frame.add(overdraft);

    enter = new Button("Enter");
    enter.addActionListener(this);
    frame.add(enter);

    done = new Button("Click to Exit");
    done.addActionListener(this);
    frame.add(done);

    setVisible(true); // GUI components set as visible to the program

}

public void readRecord() {
    DecimalFormat twoDigits = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

    try {

        do {
            data.read(input);
        } while (data.getAccount() == 0);



        input.seek(
                  (long) ( data.getAccount()-1 ) * Record.size());
                        data.write( input );

        account_num.setText(String.valueOf(data.getAccount()));
        first_name.setText(data.getFirstName());
        last_name.setText(data.getLastName());
        balance.setText(String.valueOf(twoDigits.format(data.getBalance())));
        overdraft.setText(String.valueOf(twoDigits.format(data.getOverdraft())));

    }// end try

    catch (EOFException eof) {
        closeFile();
    }

    catch (IOException e) {
        // if an error occurs display a message on the screen
        System.err.println("Error during read from file\n " + e.toString());
        // the program terminates due to error
        // System.exit(1);
    }
}

private void closeFile() {
    try {
        input.close();
        // System.exit(1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // if an error occurs display a message on the screen
        System.err.println("Error closing file\n " + e.toString());
        // System.exit(1);
    }
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == enter)
        readRecord();
    else if (e.getSource() == done)
        frame.dispose();
    else
        frame.add(new TextField(" Account Not Found on Database "));
    closeFile();

}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    new CredRead();
}
```

}

Comment: Are you sure that the file has more than one record? What have you done to debug your situation?

Comment: Also, I would test my code *outside* of a Swing GUI. Instead create the most simple program with 1 or 2 methods, that simply reads from the file and writes it to console. Simplify your problem to isolate it and debug it. Also as an aside: you don't want to mix Swing (JFrame) with AWT (Button) components.

Comment: I have the same program in AWT with he same problem and yes the RAF has 100 records

Comment: Please re-read my comment above. I'm not saying that your GUI library is contributing to your problem, but rather I am saying that it likely has **nothing to do with your problem**, and so you should isolate your problem, by creating the minimal code that demonstrates your problem and nothing more. And then post this code here. And I am sticking with my unrelated recommendation that you should not mix AWT with Swing components. This has nothing to do with your current problem, but all to do with making better GUI's.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that

data.getAccount() != 0

and so your loop only executes once, because you did it in a do ... while();

Try adding some debugging into your code and make sure what data.getAccount() is equal to.

Comment: No, I did not say you should change it to != I'm saying that your check is returning false and the loops doesn't get executed more than once.
What does this check do: while (data.getAccount() == 0)

Comment: Appologies , I am new to this and java also, I want to be able to search through my raf and look / edit / delete the records in the file, My lecturer told me that the data.getAccount will allow me to do this

Comment: No need to apologise, basically the reason you only see one result is because your loop exits after one iteration. Because of your check.
while (data.getAccount() == 0)